# drush make build script tries to download project itself from drupal.org

Tags: drush

I use a drush make build script to install a profile. Just started that install profile project.

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/groovehunter/releasemanager/master/build-releasemanager.make

When I do

```
drush make "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/groovehunter/releasemanager/master/build-releasemanager.make" -v -y
```

it prepares the core and tries to download

```
Loading release_info engine.                                                  [notice]
Unable to clone releasemanager from                                           [error]
http://git.drupal.org/project/releasemanager.git.
```

but that's oviously not successful. THe code is on github only. I have no clue where drush get the information the project lives on drupal.org ?

Cleared drush cache, also manually, but Cannot get it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems there were some wrong cached files.

I removed all ~/.drushrc/cache/git and downloads